# Add Electrical Socket to a light circuit

Tags: electrical

I have a garage in the building where I live, is equipped just of light, so switch to power on and off and the bulb at the ceiling, i don’t have any power point to plug any simple tools like drill, or car polisher or glue gun, vacuum cleaner..so I was thinking to install the electric socket to the wall running the wires from the ceiling bulb..I tried to do that, but the colors of the light circuit are different of the wires I wanna plug to the socket..I have a red and white wire plug together to the bulb, then I have a black one and a white one, the wires I bought for the socket are red,black and yellow/green (i’m Sure is the earth)..any help or any suggestion how to plug them in the right way? I’m located in Sydney so the colour code may be different.
Thanks for your help in advance.[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Presumably Sydney Australia, and not, say, Sydney Nova Scotia Canada?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: I considered asking that, and adding Sidney, BC, but thought I shouldn't...

Comment: Ok I am in the U.S. but have built equipment for overseas. Many times Red is used to signify a switched hot, it is the same as a black hot but there is a switch to turn it on and off. The green, green yellow or bare copper is ground and white/gray are neutral colors blue on your side of the pond. Where I used a wire of any color other than green , white, or gray a single stripe is used to identify that red from another red for example a multi conductor cable may have a red wire with a different colored stripe so it can be identified at each end it sounds like this may be what you have.

Comment: I have a red cable, a red and white together and a black one, how I attached to a cable that have 3 wires, one black, one red and one yellow/green?

Comment: I would like to add pictures but i don’t know how to do it

Comment: In Au/NZ hot is red and neutral is black.  These are traditional UK colors and also the standard  colors in DC wiring.   Just like everywhere else on the planet, earth is green or yellow/green or bare.

Comment: OP we need to see what's going on inside that lamp box.  There is a "maybe" in play here...

Comment: Note that if this is in Australia, it's likely that the lighting circuit is protected at a very low current. 6-10A. While it's compliant to install a socket on this circuit, you are likely to experience nuisance tripping if you use any large appliances like a vacuum cleaner, *and that will also take out your lights*.

Comment: If you don’t posses the qualifications / permits / licences then STOP fiddling.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that it is completely illegal to do *any* DIY electrical wiring work above extra-low voltage in New South Wales. You will need to engage a qualified electrician.

Comment: Good grief!  Then I would wire most of my house in ELV.  "What's that 4/0 going to?" "The hair dryer."